Why every app that is using iCloud Drive is stuck on iPadOS 17.4.1?
I have been having this kind of issue since Friday evening (2024.04.05).
It all started with the Files app not responding (not showing deleted/updated/downloaded... files), then it propagated to other apps. Every app using iCloud Drive as its base is opening with a blank browser screen (the left-side bar is usually there, but unclickable).
Now Files, PDF Viewer, Numbers, GoodNotes, ..., everything I tried that works with iCloud Drive opens to a blank screen, nothing else. After a while the app in question crashes—but not consistently. I tried to launch Mail, Safari, Acrobat, ... they all work well and as expected.
I uninstalled the Files app, and then reinstalled it. No change.
Force restart or ordinary shut-down, turn-on procedures make the system work for maybe a minute, but not always (at the moment of writing, 2024.04.08, that brings to nothing). Then everything is blocked again. I believe something happened with the outage Apple servers received last week, but my Mac and iPhone are working more than fine, and no file appears to be missing from iCloud Drive accessed on the web or on iPhone/Mac.
I tried the following steps:

Deactivate iCloud Drive for specific apps. Some improved, others didn't.
Reinstall iPadOS by downloading the restore image from the Developer portal, then Option-click on Update in Finder, forcing a reinstall of the current iPadOS. GoodNotes restored functionality, other apps didn't. The Files app keeps not being able to access iCloud Drive in a sync'd state.
Deactivate iCloud Drive on iPad. Restart the iPad. All apps resumed working normally. After reactivating iCloud Drive and waiting for most files to appear in the Files app view, I tried again. Everything but GoodNotes is once more opening on a blank screen. In the Files app, the user-created folders appeared, but trying to access them makes the spinning wheel appear on them, and one gets to nothing.
Log-out of Apple ID and restart the iPad. Verified once more that Numbers, Pages, etc... work as expected when there is no connection to Apple servers for their files. Logged-in, waited for files to download. Blocked once more.

At this point I highly doubt that a full restore would improve anything, since the iPad is working just fine for everything except for apps that use iCloud Drive.
I will surely call Apple Support is this doesn't get solved by today, but I would like to hear from you if you have any suggestion on the matter.
Thank you so much.

This was solved by restoring the iPad. Apple Support engineers said my iCloud Drive was filled with small files, leftovers of apps used in the past on the iPad. I am now dreading the next time when it will happen, because support was not helpful at all.
